# Executing perl code only on clicking <a> tag

Tags: html, perl

I want to execute some perl code only when I click on `<a>` tag, not every time the .html.ep file loads and I can't figure out how to do it.
So far I tried to put the perl code in front of the href:

```
<a <% $type = $type eq 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'; %>
                      href="<%= url_for('customer_statistics')
                          . "?sort_by=" . "date_begin"
                          . "&type=" . $type %>">
```

but it's not working because it's executing every time the page loads.
And my question is: can I execute the perl code only on clicking `<a>` tag, without using javascript?

Comment: You can't execute Perl code on the client --the browser doesn't understand Perl-- so I presume you want it to execute on the server. This means the client will need to make a request to the server. This means you want `<a href="https://...">...</a>`, where the URL causes Perl code to be executed on the server. This will of course replace the page being viewed with the output of that Perl code. If you don't want that to open, you will necessarily have to use JS (to make an AJAX request).

Comment: Looks like the Op is using https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/HTML-EP/lib/HTML/EP.pod, so it's already running as a CGI script.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using a second variable `$next_type`:

```
<th><a <% $next_type = $type eq 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'; %>
                      href="<%= url_for('customer_statistics')
                          . "?sort_by=" . "num_comments"
                          . "&type=" . $next_type %>">
                        <%= l('No. comments') %></a>
```

it  was more elegant than using JS